# Is there a shortcut key for file browser? (Equiv. of Win+E)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

In windows you can press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to get the Windows Explorer window to open up any time.

Is there an equivalent global hot-key to get the file explorer to show up in Ubuntu Karmic?

Comment: [a valuable comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483917/is-there-any-shortcut-keys-to-open-nautilus) that suggests solution to a similar question

Comment: If there a was tag indicating a question seeking equivalent Microsoft Windows functionality, it would enable users to 'round up' this class of questions.   Very useful to Windows users that are learning Ubuntu / UNIX

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Open System / Preferences / Keyboard shortcuts

Scroll down to Desktop/Home folder, click on it, then press Win+E.

Click Close.

Comment: Don't forget to remap Super to Hyper in your keyboard layout options first.

Comment: In my Pop!OS it opens just first window. How can I QUICKLY open another Files window?

Answer (score 21):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

1) Navigate to System Settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts Tab => Launchers

2) Click Home Folder and press Win+E to set the shortcut

3) When complete it should say Super+E to the right of the Home Folder

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts in System Settings]

Comment: The layout has changed in newer versions, but there is now a search bar which means it is easiest to find this shortcut by typing "Home" in there.

Answer (score 4):

You can open Nautilus by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: That's only when you have the desktop on focus. Won't work if you have something like a browser open

Answer (score 4):

**In Ubuntu 18.04**

- Press Window key,
- search 'shortcut',
- you'll have a settings menu for keyboard shortcuts. Dive in.
- go to the bottom of the screen and click '+' (Add New Shortcut)

**Set these :**

- **Name**: Home,
- **Command**: `xdg-open .` (You can replace '.' with your directory, '.' will open home directory by default).
- **Set Shortcut**: `Window-Key + E`

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, go to System Settings => Keyboard => Custom Shortcuts.

Click on `+`, write in name box for your as `Home Folder` and in command box as `nautilus`. 


[image]

Click on Add.

Now click on **`Disabled`** next to newly created "Home Folder" in Custom Shortcuts. **`Disabled`** will change to **`New Accelerator`**.

Press any key-combination e.g.<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Now it will look like below.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you are using Nautilus as file manager. You can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `nautilus`. You don't even have to finish the whole word since it will auto-complete.

Advantages of this approach are:

1. A general way of opening all programs whose (partial) name you can remember.
2. Needn't remapping keys and memorizing them.